# On-topic question on music.stack

Tags: discussion

I just joined the "Music Practise and Theory" stack to get some tips on piano performance and I note that there is a massive amount of sound-recording related questions getting hoovered up by that forum - questions that would be a significantly better fit for this stack. Is there a process by which forums can direct or migrate questions that are more on-topic elsewhere?